# Find straight line segments in image using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

Using OpenCV's findContours() I have a list of contours in an image.  I'm interested only in the straight lines, so if they are too 'squiggly' they should be rejected.  The question is how to evaluate how straight each contour is?

I looked at fitLine(), but there doesn't appear to be a goodness-of-fit measure returned.  I could evaluate this myself using the returned line.

I looked at arcLength() with the aim to compare this to the bounding rectangle dimensions, but even for somewhat straight lines, the arc length can be relatively long if the contour points are dense.

I could find the convex hull and compare to the bounding rectangle dimensions, but I'd have to analyze the convexity defects.

Is there a moment that would be useful here?

Comment: A line is not exactly a contour in an image. May I ask why you didn't use Hough Line Transformation to detect those lines?

Comment: For my problem at hand I need to find contours, but it is additionally useful to know how straight they are.

Comment: You can use sum of squares point-line distances divided by number of points as a goodness-of-fit metric.

Comment: " I'm interested *only* in the straight lines" but late " I need to find contours, but it is additionally useful to know how straight they are". Your constraints on this problem are contradictory.

Comment: try LSD: Line Segment Detector. The paper looks really nice. There is an implementation in OpenCV 3.0 but I didn't try it yet: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#linesegmentdetector

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the contours as you are doing now
2. Find the straight lines in the image using [HoughLines()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines)
3. Compute the overlap between the contours and the straight lines

Answer (score 1):

Take two points (with for instance `cv::approxPoly`) on your contour and compute their absolute distance. Then go through the contour points between the two points and add up all the distances. If the difference between distance over the contour and the absolute distance is bigger than a certain threshold you can reject it.

Answer (score 0):

The function, `findContours()` already approximated contours with line segments somehow. Each contour is represented by a list of points around it. For your purpose, simply computing the distances of each pair of consecutive points in the contour would give you all line segment lengths.

Here is an example:

```
c = cnts[0]
#d is the points in contour c shifted by one with wraparound (numpy.roll)
d = np.roll(c, 1, axis=0)
np.linalg.norm(c - d, axis = -1)
```